# Tosca puzzle 41036 solved with RBFW (title: TABLE SEARCH) : code isseu= Strip string does not strip all the characters

Tags: string, robotframework, strip

the code issue is related to the page: https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/41036

The code I used so far is:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Browser
Library    String
# title = TABLE SEARCH

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test 70310
    OPEN BROWSER  https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/41036
    ${txt}=    GET TEXT    //span[contains(text(),'Table contains')]
    #&{tostring}=  CONVERT TO STRING    ${txt}
    # don't forget the spacebar
    ${endresult}=    String.STRIP STRING        ${txt}   characters=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnop"?() /
    LOG TO CONSOLE    ${endresult}  
    FILL TEXT    xpath=//input[@id='resulttext']    ${endresult}
    #${text}=    GET TEXT    id=randomTable
    #LOG TO CONSOLE    ${text}
    Get Text         xpath=//body    *=   You solved this automation problem.
    # used resources
```

the problem is it strips it down to: *tains "15"? (True/Fals* (and I don't know why that is)

At first I thought I missed the spacebar, so I added that one in, but it didn't give the correct end result.

Comment: Hint: you're supposed to use a regex for finding the number; hint 2: you're supposed to type the word "True" or "False" in the input, not the number.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is it strips it down to: tains "15"? (True/Fals (and I don't know why that is)

Your original string is "Table contains "15"? (True/False)"

You are explicitly asking robot to remove the characters in `characters` from the string. So, it is going to remove the "T", "a", "b", "l", "e", " ", "c", "o", and "n" from the left, and "e", " ", "(", "T", "r", "u", "e", "/", "F", "a", "l", "s", "e", and ")" from the right since those are all of the characters in the `characters` parameter.

Comment: aaaaaah now I see, somehow the 'qrstuvwxyz' disappeared.